# Running remote batch file with PsExec and C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, psexec

I'm trying to run a remote batch file - already located on the remote machine - using PsExec, called via Process in C#. I've confirmed that all required files already exist, but believe I may have a problem with my syntax, as the redirected output indicates that it can't find the file specified.

The machine against which PsExec runs is dynamic, which is the myArray[0].MachineName value (this pulls in without issue).

```
wsStopProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\PsExec.exe";
wsStopProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @" \\" + myArray[0].MachineName + @"D:\stopprofile.bat";

wsStopProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
wsStopProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
wsStopProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
wsStopProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

wsStopProcess.Start();
```

Any ideas on what appears to be formatted incorrectly? I'm guessing it's too many backslashes (or not enough!) somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is you do not have a space between the two arguments.

Try this:

```
wsStopProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\" + myArray[0].MachineName + @" D:\stopprofile.bat";
```

I would also warn you that I could not get psexec to work 100%, despite trying many different things.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sadly, even with the spaces it doesn't quite behave. Here's my updated line: wsStopProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @" \\" + myArray[0].MachineName + @" D:\stopprofile.bat";

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
wsStopProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\" + myArray[0].MachineName + @" D$\stopprofile.bat";
```

So instead of using `:` try `$` sign. Also setting breakpoint on the above line while debugging will help you to see the exact path.